# Controling of bathroom light by using Magnetic Switch (Sensor)

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

I want to control bathroom light by using Magnetic Reed Switch (Sensor).
When enters inside light should be ON & after coming out light should be OFF.

Comment: In any civilized country, the electrical codes do not permit you to toss together a bunch of electronic bits and then have that handle mains power.   However, if the lighting is low voltage and under 55 watts (which from LEDs, is plenty), then the rules are much more liberal and you can indeed do that if you follow common sense rules.   Ergo I recommend a low voltage solution.

Comment: I want to use it on 230Volts 1Phase.
Not LED Light, normal light.

Comment: You may not want magnetic, unless the door is always open when unoccupied and always closed occupied.  Often “occupancy sensors” are used instead, which turn light on at first motion detection and off an adjustable number of seconds after the last motion.

Comment: @mmc711 Please [register](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) your account and then [merge](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting multiple responses as answers can result in an automated lock that can prevent others from assisting you.

Comment: then use a listed relay to switch the 230V, and have low-voltage sourced from a small listed transformer actuate the relay.   Putting 230V on a reed switch is asking for a house fire.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, constructing something from loose parts is often a local code violation. The common solution to this issue now is easier to implement, it's called an "occupancy sensor" that is built into the switch. it uses Passive Infra-Red (PIR) sensors that detect if a human (or animal) is in the room giving off heat and moving. They will have a timer built-in as well so that if you don't move for a few minutes, it doesn't go dark on you. Search for a "PIR occupancy sensor" that is available wherever you are located.